# Building custom messages on Desktop

Tags: ros, message, rxplot, rostopic, messages

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to plot a custom message with rxplot on my desktop while my Turtlebot runs. However, this fails and asks if I've built my messages? How can I build custom messages on my desktop computer?

EDIT:
You can't copy and paste from turtlebot to the desktop because the directories are different. Make files only work if they're in the proper directory. I can't roscreate a new package on the desktop in the ROS directory. I can make it anywhere else on the machine, but when I try roscreate-pkg, it's denied, and when I sudo it, roscreate-pkg the command is not found.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/43784/building-custom-messages-on-desktop/) by [IFLORbot](https://answers.ros.org/users/1978/iflorbot/) on ROS Answers with karma: 33 on 2012-09-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Never create packages in /opt/ros nor use sudo for compiling packages.

On the desktop, you need to create an [overlay](http://www.ros.org/wiki/fuerte/Installation/Overlays). Then copy the package containing your custom messages into it. If you copied the build directory in your package, too, you will run into compiler errors because the paths have changed. In that case, all you need to do is call `rosmake --pre-clean <your package>` to make sure that the old build directories are all removed.

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-09-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-09-20**:
Sure. They work since the beginning of ros and are commonly used.

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-09-20**:
It should. rosws is independent from the ros release.

**Comment by [IFLORbot](https://answers.ros.org/users/1978/iflorbot/) on 2012-09-20**:
Ok, yeah, sorry I hadn't installed it and assumed it was there.

**Comment by [IFLORbot](https://answers.ros.org/users/1978/iflorbot/) on 2012-09-20**:
Yeah, that should be it, I'm just having multiple problems either adding the overlay to the package path, or once, I do that, not having interfere with ROS_ROOT. I don't have anymore time today to fix it, so I'll try to mess with it more tomorrow.

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-09-20**:
You should not have any problems if you follow the overlay tutorial closely.

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-09-21**:
When you create the overlay with `rosws init ~/overlay /opt/ros/electric` and source ~/overlay/setup.bash  you should be able to access all normal ros packages. Verify that first. Create a subdir in ~/overlay, put your msgs in there and add it with `rosws set`. Source setup.bash again.

**Comment by [IFLORbot](https://answers.ros.org/users/1978/iflorbot/) on 2012-09-21**:
That didn't work. Set didn't add the subdirectory to ROS_PACKAGE_PATH, it seems, and it should, right?  I had it working correctly for a minute after I added all the package paths to ROS_PACKAGE_PATH, but then it reverted when I opened a new terminal.

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-09-21**:
Did you source the right setup.bash (that one in the overlay)?

**Comment by [IFLORbot](https://answers.ros.org/users/1978/iflorbot/) on 2012-09-21**:
Yes, I did.

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-09-21**:
Have a look at the file ~/overlay/.rosinstall. It should contain an entry for the directory you added using `rosws set`. setup.bash uses that file to generate the ROS_PACKAGE_PATH.

**Comment by [IFLORbot](https://answers.ros.org/users/1978/iflorbot/) on 2012-09-21**:
It does. But now there is no ROS_ROOT.

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-09-21**:
I actually doubt that. The auto-generated setup.sh should set ROS_ROOT if you initialized with `rosws init ~/overlay /opt/ros/electric`

**Comment by [IFLORbot](https://answers.ros.org/users/1978/iflorbot/) on 2012-09-21**:
It didn't. Everything seems to work fine once I reset ROS_ROOT myself. Technically, my root is /opt/ros/electric/ros, I found, so that could have been the problem. If I had set it to that, it probably would have worked without issue.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Uncomment `rosbuild_genmsg()` in CMakeLists.txt.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2012-09-13

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [IFLORbot](https://answers.ros.org/users/1978/iflorbot/) on 2012-09-13**:
That's how I do it on the laptop controlling the turtlebot, but that doesn't work on the Desktop. I can't copy the files over and I can't use roscreate since it doesn't exist on the desktop SDK.

**Comment by [IFLORbot](https://answers.ros.org/users/1978/iflorbot/) on 2012-09-17**:
I can't make since I copied the files over and the directory has changed. How can I roscreate if it doesn't exist on the Desktop?

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2012-09-17**:
The machine where rxplot runs needs to have a ROS install, where the messages exist.

**Comment by [IFLORbot](https://answers.ros.org/users/1978/iflorbot/) on 2012-09-17**:
ROS is installed, but it's the desktop SDK, which does not come with ROS create installed, which you need to make new projects, which is the only way I know how to build ros make files. Is there a way to  just build messages without using roscreate?

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2012-09-17**:
I'm not sure what the Desktop SDK is, but you shouldn't need to redo the messages package that you have on the other machine. In fact it should be an exact clone/checkout/etc. of the code on the turtlebot.

**Comment by [IFLORbot](https://answers.ros.org/users/1978/iflorbot/) on 2012-09-18**:
It is, but make files do not work if they are moved out of the directory they were created in, so I can't run it.